# Syncing the fork of a repository in GitHub Entreprise

Tags: git, github

We can compare and fetch upstream directly from github for a fork, but can we do that for github entreprise? How do we work there, do we follow the old method of managing it through the local git commands?
I want the fastest and most efficient way for syncing the fork with the original repo

I am currently resolving it through a series of various local git commands

Answer (score 0):

The Sync a Fork process is available for:

- [GHES 3.6](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.6/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork), where you can fetch and merge an upstream branch to your fork.

[image: fetch and merge]

- [GHES 3.7](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork), where you can "`Update Branch`"

[image: Update Branch]

In both instances, no need for local git commands.

Comment: Oh okay, seems like my version of GitHub enterprise is older one, I have 3.1

Comment: @AmeyVarhade Makes sense: that feature started with 3.3.